# How do I sort this list of lists in that matches two conditions?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists that looks like this [[value, frequency], ... , [value, frequency]]. I wish to sort it in:

1. descending order by frequency
2. if two frequencies have the same value then I want to sort those lists in ascending order by value.

Example:
**[[7,1], [8,2], [4,3], [3,2] --sorted--> [[4,3], [3,2], [8,2], [7,1]]**

I've tried sorting the list in descending order by frequency like follows:
 `sorted(list, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)` but this doesn't take care of the second condition
Appreciate the help!

Comment: `key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`

Comment: Well, as usual, I'm midway through writing an answer and then suddenly the question is closed. I don't know why I bother. None of the answers at the marked duplicate address the problem of sorting **descending** according to one criterion, and **ascending** according according to another. I'm sure there are other duplicates that do address it, but not this one.

Comment: @Stef You're right, this duplicate doesn't answer the question and the solution given by azro doesn't work either. I've looked at some other duplicates but no luck so far.

Comment: @ParthPatel What do you mean, "the solution by azro doesn't work either"? It should work. What happens when you try it?

Comment: @ParthPatel In your question you apparently have a list named `list`. In python that's pretty bad. `list` is already the name of builtin class `list`. Shadowing the name of a builtin is confusing and can have unintended consequences.